# Search by product color - WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been trying for some time now to figure out the correct $args-array for making a custom search form, allowing the user to search for products by name, description and custom WooCommerce attributes (as for now by color).

Is this possible using the WP_Query at all or do I need to alter the built in search function? And if so - how?

Here's the $args-options I've been trying for now:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'no_found_rows' => true,
    'post_type' =>  array('product'),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'oct-search',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array($_POST["search_string"]),
        ),
    ),
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I solved this on my own hand, using this code:

```
$attributes =  'oct-shade';
$attributes = 'pa_'.$attributes;
$filters = explode(',', $_POST["search_string"]);
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'no_found_rows' => true,
    'post_type' =>  array('product'),
    'tax_query' =>
    array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy'      => "$attributes",
            'field'         => 'slug',
            'terms'         => $filters,
            'operator'      => 'IN'
        ),
    ),
);
```